# Is $\text{arc2sinh}(\dots(\exp(2\sinh(\dots z))$ an entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $^{*n}$ denote the $n$-th iteration and $z$ be a complex number. Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $2\sinh(z)$ be $\exp(z)-\exp(-z)$ and $\text{arc2sinh}$ its functional inverse.
Is the limit for $n$ to $+\infty$ of $\text{arc2sinh}^{*n}(\exp(2\sinh^{*n}(z)))  = f(z)$ an entire function in the variable $z$ ? Does $f(z)$ converge everywhere ?

Comment: Please clean up your notation using LaTeX, and explaining what your non-standard $arc2sinh$ and such mean.

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant $\,\operatorname{arcsinh}^2(...\,$ ...? Not that this makes the problem easier, of course.

Comment: Actually, if $2\sinh\text{^}^{n}(x)$ means $2\sinh(2\sinh(\ldots 2\sinh(x)))$ and $\text{arc2sinh^}^{n}(x)$ is the corresponding inverse function. It is not hard to show $f(z)$ cannot be entire. On the real axis, $f(z)$ converges to $2\sinh(z)$ for $z \ge 0$ and $0$ for $z < 0$.

Comment: I fixed LaTeX kinda. 
Plz explain achille hui ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x) = 2\sinh(x) =e^x - e^{-x}$ and $g^{[-1]}(x)$ be $g$'s functional inverse.
More generally, for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we define:

$$g^{[n]}(x) = \begin{cases}\underbrace{g(g(\cdots(g(x)))}_{n\,\text{times}} & n > 0\\x & n = 0\\ \overbrace{g^{[-1]}(g^{[-1]}(\cdots(g^{[-1]}(x)))}^{|n|\,\text{times}} & n < 0\end{cases}$$

Notice $\frac{d}{dx}g^{[-1]}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$, $g^{[-1]}$ is a contraction mapping over $\mathbb{R}$:

$$|g^{[-1]}(x_1) - g^{[-1]}(x_2)| \le \frac12 |x_1 - x_2|,\,\,\,\forall x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$$

For any $x > 0$, we have $g(x) > 2 x$. This implies:

$$\begin{align}
& g^{[n]}(x) > 2^n x\\
\implies & g^{[n+1]}(x) < \exp(g^{[n]}(x)) = g^{[n+1]}(x) + e^{-g^{[n]}(x)} < g^{[n+1]}(x) + e^{-2^n x}\\
\implies &  g(x) < g^{[-n]}(\exp(g^{[n]}(x))) < g(x) + 2^{-n} e^{-2^n x}
\end{align}$$

Taking limit $n \to \infty$, we get $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} g^{[-n]}(\exp(g^{[n]}(x))) = g(x)$ for $x > 0$.

For any $x \le 0$, we have $g(x) \le -2|x|$. This means:

$$\begin{align}
&g^{[n]}(x) \le -2^n|x|\\
\implies & 0 \le \exp(g^{[n]}(x)) \le e^{-2^n|x|}\\
\implies & 0 \le g^{[-n]}(\exp(g^{[n]}(x))) \le 2^{-n} e^{-2^n|x|}
\end{align}$$

Taking limit again, we get $f(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$. From this, we can conclude $f(z)$ cannot be analytic over any neighborhood of $z = 0$ and hence is not an entire function.

**EDIT**

About what happens for $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, This is a summary on what I know:

Let $R_{n}$, $I_{n}$ be the sets

$$R_{n} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : g^{[n]}(z) \in \mathbb{R} \} \,\,\,\text{ and } \,\,\,
  I_{n} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : g^{[n]}(z) \in i \mathbb{R} \}$$

Let $R = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} R_n$ and
    $I = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$ be their union.
It is not hard to show:

- $\mathbb{R} \subset R_1 \subset R_2 \subset \cdots \subset R$ and 
  i$\mathbb{R} \subset I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \cdots \subset I$.
- $R$ and $I$ has measure zero.
- $f(z)$ is defined on $R \cup I$.
- $f(z) = 0$ on $I$.

  - If $c \in I$, then $g^{[n]}(c)$ lands on the imaginary axis $i\mathbb{R}$ for large $n$. The $\exp(\cdot)$ in $f$ will send $i\mathbb{R}$ into the unit disk where $g^{[-1]}$ is defined and is a contraction
- $f(z) = 0$ on *half* of $R\setminus I$.

  - If $c \in R_n\setminus I$, so does $c + \pi i$. Since $g^{[n]}(c+\pi i) = -g^{[n]}(c) \ne 0$, one and only one of $c$ and $c+\pi i$ lands on the negative real axis and the corresponding $f(z)$ vanishes.

**EDIT2**

On $\mathbb{C} \setminus ( R \cup I )$, I don't have a proof but I believe $f(z)$ 
<strike>isn't defined at all.</strike> either converges to $0$ or not defined at all.

[image: A plot of R_3 and I_3]

If one plot $R_n$ and $I_n$ for $n > 1$ on same graph, one will notice $R_n$ and $I_n$ intermixes quickly when $z$ moves away from the origin. Remember $g(z)$ is an "expansion" map for $z \sim 0$. Even if we start will a small $z$, repeat iteration will quickly bring
$g^{[n]}(z)$ away from $0$ and into the region when $R_n$ and $I_n$ intermixed thoroughly.

However, there are exceptions to this fate. $g(z)$ has two (and only two) stable fix points $\pm z_{st} \sim \pm 1.895494267 i$. If for some $k$, $g^{[k]}(z)$ lands close enough to these two fix points, further iteration of $g$ will quickly pull them to $\pm z_{st}$. The $g^{[-n]}$ part in $f$'s definition will then force $f(z) = 0$.

Aside from this exception, I cannot see other way to stop $g^{[-n]}(\exp(g^{[n]}(z))$ from wandering around the complex plane and let us define $f(z)$.

Comment: It seems you proved what $f(x)$ is on the real line.
Can you show how $f(x)$ is on the complex plane ? For instance if for $Re(z)>0$ we have $f(z)=g(z)$ ?

Comment: @mick I don't think so, see update of answer.